# Cached image goes back to previous image when updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I want to add a new image to the my users profile, the image initially shows up fine. When I go in and out of the view, the image reverts back to the old image.

The part that is stumping me is if I would again, leave the view and go back in, the new image shows the second time the view appears. Not sure what is going on.

**Cached class**

```
class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    @Published var urlString: String?
    var imageCache = CacheImageManager.getImageCache()
     @Published var isLoading = false
     
     init (urlString: String?) {
         self.urlString = urlString
         loadImage()
     }
  
    func loadImage() {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return
        }
        
        if image != nil {
            print("Image already loaded")
            return
        }
        
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            print("cache located")
            return
        }
        
        print("cache not detected")
        loadImageFromURL()
    }
    
    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            print("urlString is nil")
            return false
        }
        
        print("cache LOADING: \(imageCache)")
        
        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.getCache(forKey: urlString) else {
            print("cache not found for key: \(urlString)")
            return false
        }
        
        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }

    func loadImageFromURL (){
        isLoading = true // show loading indicator
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
                 return
             }
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler:
                                                   getImageFromResponse(data: response: error: ))
           task.resume()
    }
    
    func getImageFromResponse (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // switch to the main thread
            self.isLoading = false // hide loading indicator
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no data for image found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            self.imageCache.setCache(forKey: self.urlString!, image: loadedImage)
            self.image = loadedImage
        }
    }
}

class CacheImageManager {
    static let shared = CacheImageManager()
    private lazy var cache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = {
        let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
        cache.countLimit = 100
        cache.totalCostLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100
        return cache
    }()
    
    func getCache(forKey key: String) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: NSString(string: key))
    }
    
    func setCache(forKey key: String, image: UIImage) {
        print("LOADING CACHE")
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: key))
    }
}
extension CacheImageManager{
    private static var imageCache = CacheImageManager()
    static func getImageCache() -> CacheImageManager {
        imageCache
    }
}
```

**Profile Picture**

```
 private func persistImageToStorage() {
            guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let ref = FirebaseManager.shared.storage.reference(withPath: uid)
        
            guard let imageData = self.inputImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
            ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
                if let err = err {
                   print("failed to push to storage \(err)")
                    return
                }

                ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("failed to fetch download link")
                        return
                    }
                    
                   print("Image saved Successfully")
                    
                    guard let url = url else { return }
                  
                    //save to firestore
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData([ "profilePicture": url.absoluteString ], merge: true)
                }
            }
        }

 VStack{
                UrlImageView(urlString: profilePicURL, inputImage: $inputImage)
                    
                Button(action: {
                   ShowPicker()
                   
                }){
                    Image(systemName:("plus.circle.fill"))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonTwo"))
                        .frame(width:30, height:25)
                       
                       
                }
                .padding(.top, -20)
                .padding(.leading, 50)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
           
    
        //SAVE IMAGE TO DATABASE (FIREBASE)
        .onChange(of: inputImage, perform: { _ in
            persistImageToStorage() //call to save function
        })

struct UrlImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var urlImageModel: UrlImageModel
    @State var pictureUpdated = false
    @Binding var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State var cachedImage: UIImage?
    init(urlString: String?, inputImage: Binding<UIImage?>) {
           urlImageModel = UrlImageModel(urlString: urlString)
           _inputImage = inputImage
       }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let image = inputImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(color: Color("LightWhite"), radius: 9, x: 0, y: 13)
                    .onAppear{
                        print("this is A")
                    }
            }  else {
                Image(uiImage: urlImageModel.image ?? ProfilePicture.placeholderProfileImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(color: Color("LightWhite"), radius: 9, x: 0, y: 13)
                    .onAppear{
                        print("this is c")
                       
                    }
            }
    }

}
```

Update:
Tried removing the cache when the new image was added, but still yielded same results

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` for objects owned by a view -- you should be using `@StateObject`